# Show that the set of real numbers regarded as a vector space over the field of rational numbers is infinite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This was one of the exercises on the section about maximal linearly independent subsets (MLISs) and the Hausdorff Maximal Principle and all that. The full exercise asks:

> Let $V$ be the set of real numbers regarded as a vector space over the field of rational numbers. Show that $V$ is infinite-dimensional. *Hint: Use the fact that $\pi$ is transcedental, that is, it is not the zero of any polynomial with rational coefficients.*

My first approach was to use contradiction and assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional with the base as $\{ v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n \}$ and so $\pi$ can be expressed as
$$
\pi = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + \cdots + a_n v_n
$$
The only other equation I set up was
$$
b_m\pi^m + b_{m-1} \pi^{m-1} + \cdots + b_1 \pi + b_0 \neq 0 \qquad \text{for all } b_i \in \mathbb{Q}
$$

And then I got stuck. I don't know where to proceed from here or how to utilize the topics discussed in the chapter. The only connection I could make was the similarity between polynomials and linear combinations. Could somebody give me a *small* hint? When I mean small I don't mean "solve the whole problem for me and leave the last step as the hint," I mean I would prefer to solve this exercise with **minimal help**. I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Also, my knowledge of linear algebra isn't that extensive (this is only the final section of chapter 1 which is vector spaces) so please don't pull out advanced concepts out of nowhere.

Comment: Instead of only expressing $\pi$ in your basis, express $\pi,\pi^2,...,\pi^{n+1}$ in your basis. Can you use those expressions to construct a polynomial equation with $\pi$ as a root?

Comment: Hint: If $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a finite dimension, say $n$, can the set $\{1, \pi, \pi^2, ..., \pi^{n}\}$ be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cardinality argument. Suppose it was a finite dimensional space, and let $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ be a basis. (Remember the real numbers are uncountable and rationals are countable).

**DO NOT READ FURTHER IF YOU STILL WANT TO TRY TO DO IT YOURSELF**

Then you could count every real number as every real number would be able to be written (uniquely) as $r_1 \cdot u_1 + \ldots + r_n \cdot u_n$, where the $r_i$ are rational numbers.

You can count every n-tuple $\left({p_1 \over q_1},\ldots,{p_n \over q_n}\right)$ of rational numbers, for example by converting it into a (n+1)-tuple of integers, by setting $l = lcm(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$, then each of those n-tuples corresponds (uniquely) to: $\left({lp_1 \over q_1},\ldots, {lp_n \over q_n}, l\right)$, which you can more easily count. This would therefore imply the real numbers be countable, which they're not.

I'll leave being able to count all (n+1)-tuples of integers as an exercise, though one idea would be to let $k$ be a non-negative integer, count every tuple $(s_1,\ldots,s_{n+1})$ of integers such that $|s_1| + \ldots + |s_{n+1}| =k$ for every $k$ starting at $0$.